# Session variable does not maintain value

Tags: c#, session

I am trying to store a datatable in a session variable but the session variable loses its values after the method where it is assigned.

I have also tried the alternate option of creating a class and storing the value in a property of the class, but even then I am not able to retain the value.

I also have tried Viewstate. I have a Sharepoint project so I am not able to add the session tag with the timeout option in web config.

Can anyone please advise as I am trying to store value in one event handler and use it in another but the value get erased / lost when the add watch option is added.

Comment: are you declaring and asecing session with its name and also are you storing in session array

Comment: At the very least, start by posting a [MCVE]

Comment: i have provided him all possible solution but not marking my answer up or correct

Comment: Hi Guys, I am still having an issue like the static variable / Session variable assigned inside the try block loses it value once the finally block is reached, but I do not perform any operation with the variable inside the finally block, this is befuddling ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Declaring datatable 

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 //storing datatable into session in this way

    Session.Add("emp", dt);

  //acessing in that way

    DataTable employee= Session["emp"] as DataTable
```

in web.config file add

```
  <configuration>
         <system.web>
                <sessionSate mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="940"/> 
           </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Comment: Have tried all three formatting option of marking as serializable, web config entry and the session attribute but still facing the error message that is posted above

Answer (score 0):

I had found out the root cause of the issue, I had used the session initialize statement inside the try block followed by the finally block. And in the finally clock I had disposed the view that was assigned to the session variable , and it is here that the session variable loses its value and becomes empty, also tried storing the value in class level static variable which was also emptied in the finally block where the source view was disposed, I am not sure why.

**Solution**
I had solved the issue by implementing my own version of the dispose method where the data-view was completely nullified.